# phpurple compile error - php 5.3

Tags: php, compiler-errors

I`m trying to compile phpurple. I`m doing everything according to the documentation: 
hxxp://phurple.php.belsky.info/ch02.html

but "make" gives me an error:

```
/myhomedir/phpurple/purple.c: In function ‘call_custom_method’:
/myhomedir/phpurple/purple.c:1370: error: ‘zend_fcall_info’ has no member named ‘object_pp’
/myhomedir/phpurple/purple.c:1408: error: ‘zend_fcall_info_cache’ has no member named ‘object_pp’
```

I`ve found other people with the same problem: 
hxxp://www.mail-archive.com/monetdb-bugs@lists.sourceforge.net/msg05515.html 
hxxp://belsky.info/archives/23-Phurple-per-se-PHPurple.html

but nobody gives any information about successful php 5.3 build and the message

> PROJECT IS CLOSED 
> if you want
>   commercial support for php 5.3, let me
>   know ... )

does not help at all.

does anyone have any idea how to compile it or any clue how to fix the problem ?

P.S. Sorry about the links, some strange StackOverflow limitation

Comment: It looks like that php 5.3 internal API has changed in a way that makes phpurple incompatible with it; so the problem can only be fixed by updating phpurple's source code.

Comment: You can't add links because your reputation is too low.

Answer (score 1):

According to `phpurple` [requirements](http://phurple.php.belsky.info/ch01.html):

```
 Please let me know, if you've successfully compiled on
 earlier versions. Actually the extension is being developed
 on the php v5.2.6 with the option to be upcomming php v5.3
 compatible.
```

The authors will need to update their source.  However, since you have the source you could update it yourself because you noted that the project is *CLOSED*.  You could also fork the code and create your own gitHub project with php 5.3 support.

Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

What you are seeing is PHP's shifty interface (ahem, hold your down votes, I said **s h i f t y**). By that, I mean function prototypes are subject to change from version to version. Take this meta example:

```
int foo_call_bar(const char *foobar, size_t len);
```

And in a later version of something, the function calculates the length dynamically, thus eliminating the second variable in the prototype:

```
int foo_call_bar(const char *foobar);
```

Some projects strive to always maintain backwards compatibility to alleviate this headache, which could be accomplished with pre-processor directives that prototype the new implementation with the `len` variable, but just don't do anything with it. If PHP did that, the code base would succumb to even more madness.

Unfortunately, you'll have to modify phpurple to present the correct arguments to the correct PHP functions, and ensure that they are of the appropriate *type*. That would be a bit of an undertaking, but probably wouldn't be as difficult as it seems.

The Linux kernel's VFS interface is the same way, and I'm often tasked with porting older experimental file systems to work on modern kernels.

Answer (score 0):

look at that man

http://sourceforge.net/news/?group_id=235197&id=296063

Answer (score 0):

A little late, but here is the latest library that works with PHP 5.3:

The new project page is: http://sourceforge.net/projects/phurple

The blog post: http://belski.net/archives/23-Phurple-per-se-PHPurple.html

I have ran into a problem after I have complied it and added the extension to PHP.ini configuration:

```
PHP Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/modules/phurple.so' - /usr/lib/php/modules/phurple.so: undefined symbol: ZVAL_ADDREF in Unknown on line 0
```

To fix this, change the line containing ZVAL_ADDREF in client.c from

```
ZVAL_ADDREF(PHURPLE_G(phurple_client_obj));
```

to

```
Z_ADDREF_P(PHURPLE_G(phurple_client_obj));
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, the new URL seems to be a persistent repo with fixes to PHP-5.3 and above. Maybe that should be mentioned, but that won't help with checking it out anyway. For me it worked fine, so I would say it is worth a try.

Comment: The guy announced a new release, look here http://belski.net/archives/37-Phurple-for-PHP-5.3-and-up.html PHP 5.4 looks fine to me, finally it works as there is no alternative.

Answer (score -1):

You can check the new sources shortly posted on https://github.com/weltling/phurple